# Dynamic switching of fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My Activity contains two buttons (Next and Back) and a fragment. When the Activity starts, it gets an array of resources.
Such as {"Fish", "Bird", "Animal"};
Or this {"Fish", "Bird", "Animal", "Bird", "Bird"}; etc.
Depending on the contents of the array, the Next button should switch the fragments accordingly:
So: Fragment_Fish.java >Fragment_Bird.java>Fragment_Animal.java.
So: Fragment_Fish.java >Fragment_Bird.java>Fragment_Animal.java. >Fragment_Bird.java>Fragment_Bird.java>

How is it easier to implement in Java, please tell me?

Comment: share your code. also explain how do you expect the app to guess wich fragment you want to switch for...

Comment: If the first element of the array is Fish, then the first fragment Fragment_Fish.java . If the second element of the array is Bird, then when the Next button is clicked, the fragment is Fragment_Fish.java is replaced by the fragment Fragment_Bird.java and so on.
The application will guess which fragment you want to switch to by the order of words in the array.

Comment: post your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to make an array of the fragments like this:

```java
Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[]]{new Fragment_Fish(), and other fragments separated with commas};
```

2. Make a int variable in the class something like this:

```java
int counter = 0;
```

3. Increase the counter on button click and update the fragment. Like this:

```java
buttonNext.setOnClickListener(v -> {
   counter ++;
   if(!counter >= fragments.size()){
      //all the fragments are opened do what you need
      return;
   }
   final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
   ft.replace(R.id.details, fragments[counter]); 
   ft.commit(); 
   //came to another fragment
});
```

Comment: `Or this {"Fish", "Bird", "Animal", "Bird", "Bird"};` how is this answer going to work if OP has two entries in the array for the same type of animal ? sounds like this needs to be a dynamic array of fragments built up based on some other criteria first

Comment: well, OP did ask about that, it's in their question ? i copied that exactly from their post, either way, there isn't enough information here to attempt an answer as you'd just be guessing

Comment: doesn't sound like OP really needs an array of fragments, they need a hashmap of fragments. your idea of making use of an array isn't going to scale and isn't going to work for cases where the same animal is needed twice

Comment: ok. I get it @a_local_nobody. That is right. We can use hashmap also. Do u want me to add that too?

Comment: doesn't matter at this point, the question is closed, i'm saying that you should not just jump to the first solution that comes to mind and you should attempt to answer well-asked questions, you'll earn a lot more reputation instead of guessing at low quality posts

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem clearly, I think you want to switch between fragments.

If you want to switch between multiple fragments, you can use **navigation components** for this.
You can explore about navigation components.

Resources :- [Integrate the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#integrate)

Comment: `I don't understand your problem clearly, ` best to not try and answer then, as you'd just be guessing, you have enough reputation to ask for clarity with comments, wait until there's enough information to actually answer correctly